# Death cause Paradox

Tags: paradox

In the sentence:

"Two guys killing themselves by jumping out of a roof"

What is the actual death cause? the roof or themselves?

Comment: Hi riki - welcome to Puzzling SE! Reading the puzzle, it seems like the "answer" can be either and both could be defended based on a users thought process - sort of like the [Chicken or the Egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg). Questions asked should have one unique and clear answer.

Comment: Oh, got it. this is a paradox, not a puzzle actually, i'm gonna remove the post then

Comment: i dont know if you see my comment down so i put here too:Do not do it !!!!!!! I started just like you (I came from another site), the way to succeed is just by experimenting! Remember: "Try Again. Fail again.Fail better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask me, their death cause is:

> the sidewalk,If it was a mattress, nothing would happen them.

And  also welcome to  website @riki481,I wish you good luck!

Comment: Thanks mate! I started in stack overflow, now i'm trying other places

Comment: @ riki481 Wish you the best, continue to raise questions you have a good vibe.

Comment: i've decided to stop. i don't have skills to answer anything in this site and don't have creativity to make more questions, so bye bye

Comment: Do not do it !!!!!!! I started just like you (I came from another site), the way to succeed is just by experimenting! Remember: "Try Again. Fail again.Fail better"

Comment: i don't feel confortable making posts here. same thing happens even  today in stack overflow. I just have 5 bagdes and 7 reputation, is not much. i rather let the smarts make their stuff than trying to make something myself and get punished by others because i wasn't good enough.

Comment: and... there is this thing: "ohhh, a new riddle!" oh, they already answered it "new puzzle" they already answered or it's too complicated for me

Comment: Right, you're not good, you're great !!! Give it another chance to try the riddles with the tags: "riddles " or "knowledge" are usually simpler for beginners.

Comment: There can be a few patronizing people here but try me to get +1 on the first attempt no matter what, I promise

Comment: My account is going to be deleted in 2 hours and 10 minutes. bye mate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92505/discussion-between-tahel-and-riki481).

Comment: I do not believe it, it's a pity that you are the most talented, however successful way to your personal journey, I am glad I was given the opportunity to meet you and your wonderful riddle,bye my friend....